# Bootstrap 3 "container-fluid" inside fixed position container prevents select from expanding to fit its items

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using Bootstrap 3 and `container-fluid`, I'm having an issue in which a multi-select is being sized *smaller* than the width of its longest item, even when there is plenty of room for it to expand.

The `fluid-container` exists inside of a fixed-position container, which seems to be relevant. (This is necessary, because in the real app this is a modal popup implemented as a fixed-position overlay)

https://jsfiddle.net/LLa2g7ak/2/

As shown here, there is plenty of room for the fixed-position container (with the drop shadow) to expand horizontally. And yet, the listbox needs a scrollbar.

[image: screenshot 1]
If I use a really, really long list item, then it *does* get wider, so there's obviously no artificial constraint being applied.

[image]

And if I put other stuff on the page that causes the container to get wider, the listbox DOES get sized correctly. (See https://jsfiddle.net/jLeqhqrh/1/)
[image]

So why is the listbox sized too narrow for its contents when it could easily expand to show them?

Answer (score 0):

First, container-fluid doesn't have a width.

Second, when you use position: fixed; or position: absolute;, the element is taken out of the regular flow of the document. The default setting for width for a div element is auto.

Div class `modalPopupWindow` have `max-width: 1487px;` and in this way it increase dimension with the content dimension and the multi select have width 100% of his container (col-md-9). So if the content of the multi select is bigger, overflow is applied to the multi select.

Sorry for my not so good english, but i hope you understand my explanation.